# PHP/mySQL get_file_contents and update the column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL db table. One of the table columns contains URLs which point to different xml files on a remote server.

My goal is to read each URLs info and write the xml content into another column on the same record (line) respectively.

In my PHP code, I am able to get the URL correctly from mySQL database and I am able to get the XML content on remote server into a variable correctly.

But the issue is while I write the content to my table line by line. Some XML columns got update correctly and some XML columns are empty.

I am pretty sure each time the variable got content correctly because I am able to print out each individual content on screen.

Why are some content updating the column and some don't. All the XML strings have the same format. If I copied that content and updated the mysql table manually, it successfully wrote into the table.

At beginning I thought it was time issue so I add enough sleep time for my PHP code. it does't help. then I suspected my db datatype, so I changed the XML
column data type from VCHAR to TEXT and even LONGTEXT. it does't help either. Does any one have a clue?

part of my php code below...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT url_txt FROM mytable ");

//work with result line by line:
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo  $url_content = file_get_contents($row['url_txt']);

//debug line below *******************************/
 echo $URL=$row[url_txt]; 
//debug line above********************************/
 mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE mytable SET xml_info='$url_content' where url_txt = '$URL' "); 

   }
```

Comment: The way you use the mysqli db connector makes your code vulnerable to sql injection. Read about "prepared statements"!

Comment: Most likely this is also your issue: broken sql statements due to sql injection. This happens for example if `$url_content` contains stuff like quoting chars which are not handled correctly the way you construct your statement. I suggest you dump the created sql statements instead of running them for a test. Then take a closer look at one that does not work and you will realize what the problem is.

Comment: What @arkascha said + if "running manually" means updating the rows using phpmyadmin, the phpmyadmin will escape the input for you. If your xml data are all in same format, please include some examples in the question

Comment: ...or url_encode the data before updating the database. Any invalid chars will be 'validated'.

Comment: @GavinSimpson No No No! First this is the wrong strategy, second why `urlencode()`? we are not talking about URLs because third `$url_content` contains file content, not URLs and fourth your "validated" would mean they are actually altered which is not what the OP wants!

Comment: @arkascha, sorry mate, u r correct. I meant htmlspecialchars.

Comment: @arkascha, thank for your tips. I think the specially characters in  my XML file cause the problem. I will try prepared statement...

Comment: issue solved by "prepared statements" . thanks again @arkascha

Comment: Great you solved it! Continue the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try converting your XML to a native array and working with it that way:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($url_content)),TRUE);
```

Comment: Programming is at least 60% a guessing game.

Comment: Then you are one of those millions of guys who is permanently guessing instead of programming. I never understood that approach. It is so time consuming and typically leads to horrible results. A hint: one can actually learn how to program. _shaking my head_

Comment: And you must be one of those people who makes assumptions based on 2 lines of text.. ass

Comment: Why assumption? You yourself clearly stated, that in your eyes programming consists of 60% guessing. That is clearly and definitely wrong.

Comment: LOL tell that to Bill Gates.. he still hasn't gotten it right.

Comment: Programming is subjective, just like any other art form.

Comment: With so many ways to do things. it is often a guess on choosing the right one to suite the current needs. Investigating beforehand which is the right one could be just as time consuming. But be nice guys.

Comment: I think that we can at least all agree that answering questions on SO is often a guessing game ;P

Comment: @Adelphia, thank you for your help, but my xml is not well-formed